# Submit JSON data to server using normal HTTP POST from browser

Tags: json, http-post

Is it possible to submit a JSON data to the server using HTTP POST and not by using AJAX. Usually information that is sent to the server when we submit using POST/GET are send in `key=value` form. How could we send a JSON Data to server in POST and not as a `key=value` pair?
I tried using `application/json` as the form encoding type as mentioned [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-json-forms/). That didn't help :-(
Is there any approach that we can try to get this thing working?

Comment: There are tons of web-browser extensions that can help with this.  I use Postman for Google Chrome.

Comment: But not all users will have these browser extensions right? We wanted to have this in a application that will go live.

Comment: Sorry I thought you were trying to use your personal Web browser to make a request.  If your using javascript, there are tons of examples out there.  Not sure what your looking for if you don't want to use Ajax however.

Comment: Can you please share one approach? We want to do a normal HTTP POST (not AJAX) and pass the JSON data to the action URL. It should not be send in form of key-value

Comment: Alternatives to Ajax: http://www.jscripters.com/alternatives-to-ajax/